# White compound, insoluble in water, turns pink and then white again on adding water

Tags: experimental-chemistry, color, identification

> Which white, ionic compound(s) that is insoluble in water turns pink when you add only a little of water but white again when you add more water?

I know that the cation is one of the following:

$$\ce{Mg^2+, Ca^2+, Sr^2+, Ba^2+, Fe^3+, Ni^2+, Co^2+, Zn^2+, Al^3+, or NH4^+}$$

I was physically examining such a compound and determined it does not change the color of litmus paper (red or blue). I thought that it could be zinc carbonate because it also precipitates hydroxide (when then compound is added to dilute nitric acid).

**EDIT:** I found out that the compound is lithium carbonate, and it just took a long time to dissolve. How would lithium carbonate change color like this?

Comment: Reversible color change reminds me immediately complexation, and in this case maybe a complex only stable when there is very less amount of water around. However, if it is really insoluble as stated I can't know. 
And the question is a riddle like one, do you have any effort on solving this question, if so edit and share it after the question, please.

Comment: I landed here because i am looking for some ingredient of ash (Wood fire, possibly some metal) that turns rose/pink if a fresh twig smoulders on top (my guess was that this is due to water vapor), but stays ash-colored in the rain. So i hope somebody will answer this.

Comment: I found out it was lithium carbonate. Why did this happen?

Comment: @Bob Where'd you get the answer from? The sources may help us.

Comment: I was told. The compound was known by someone else.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/96539/white-compound-insoluble-in-water-turns-pink-and-then-white-again-on-adding-wa?rq=1